# Быстро – по-быстрому

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, синтаксис, наречия, причастный-оборот

Пожалуйста, скажите, какой вариант правильный.

Тысчонки гирлянд, в пустынчонке, лунным таки песком засыпанной, висящие туда-сюда **быстро-по-быстрому**, были-таки дотла сожжены.

Или **быстро – по-быстрому**? Или **быстро  по-быстрому**?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147795/discussion-on-question-by-pumpkin-777----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Опять вам двойка. Опять безграмотно пишете. 1) Висящий — это статическое, нельзя быстро висеть. 2) Туда-сюда висеть тоже нельзя, потому что туда-сюда — это о направлении движения, а в висении нет движения. Ну а "быстро по-быстрому", конечно, неверно, так писать нельзя, это вообще безграмотно. Скорее всего, русский у вас не родной, не станет носитель так неправильно писать. Даже в разговорной речи до такого не опускаются, даже те, кто не знает грамоту.

Comment: @Оleed, согласен с вами .

Answer (score 1):

> Тысчонки гирлянд, в пустынчонке, лунным таки песком засыпанной,
> висящие туда-сюда **быстро по-быстрому**, были-таки дотла сожжены.

Смысл этого предложения станет чуть (чуть-чуть!) понятнее, если изменить пунктуацию:

*Тысчонки гирлянд в пустынчонке, лунным таки песком засыпанной, висящие туда-сюда, **быстро, по-быстрому** были-таки дотла сожжены.*

Answer (score 1):

Ну не знаю... Может, упростим для начала?

Тысячи гирлянд в пустыне, засыпанной лунным таки песком, висящие туда-сюда быстро, по-быстрому, были-таки дотла сожжены.

Считаю, что перед "в пустыне" ("в пустынчонке") запятая не нужна.

Причастие "висящие" (нужно прошедшее время — висевшие) относится к гирляндам, а между ними уже есть другой причастный оборот, относящийся к пустыне (необходимо переставлять).
Надо заменить: трепыхавшиеся, болтавшиеся, дергавшиеся.

*Быстро, по-быстрому* — ставим запятую, *по-быстрому* (= стремительно) *быстро* — нет.

Добавим еще каких-нибудь окказиональностей.
Можно так:
*Тысчонищи гирляндищ, трепыхавшихся туда-сюда по-быстрому быстро, были-таки дотла сожжены в пустынчонке, лунным таки песком засыпанной.*
Или так:
*В пустынульке, лунным таки песком засыпанной, были-таки дотла сожжены тысчонки гирлянд, болтавшихся туда-сюда по-быстрому быстро.*

Comment: А быстро может быть не по-быстрому? Нет. Это как молочное молоко.

Comment: "Пустынчонка" — это перебор. На мой взгляд, это словесный урод. 0 результатов в Гугл.

Comment: Теперь уже не ноль... *Стаю относило на север, но они боролись с ветром, летели, как всегда, строем, быстро, но неторопливо* (С. Лагерлёф).

Comment: 0 с "пустынчонка". По-быстрому и торопливо (ускорение) — это разные вещи, они не пересекаются. "Пустынолька" тоже ужасно. Это не русский язык. Вы Pumpkin'а переплюнули. Заигрались. Можно же было нормальное придумать (например, "пустынище"). Чтобы звучало...

Comment: То же слово не может дать нового значения. Проблема в том, что быстро — это всегда по-быстрому. Чистый плеоназм. Это как "быстро с быстротой". Между ними даже можно поставить знак равенства.

Comment: А чегой-то вам не нравится? Изобретать так изобретать — пустынулька, пустынулечка... Автору, похоже, была нужна малюсенькая пустынька (по аналогии: крохотулька, крохотулечка). Бескрылый вы какой-то, немечтательный, не витающий... Кстати, правильно **пустынища** (ж. р.) — если о большой засушливой площади.

Comment: У меня вообще звучит похоже на "простыня". Вот оно сюда ближе по звучанию. По словообразованию диссертации защищают. Там много нюансов и много ограничений. Каждому слову своё, любое вешать не получится (не русский язык). Рассматривал "пустынища", но у меня не звучит. Тяготение к среднему. Есть же более-менее нормальное — "пустыночка", не надо издеваться над языком. Не заражайтесь от Pumpkin'а, а он очень заразный (чуть ли не все подражают).

Comment: А прикиньте, если его произведения прочитать. Да от этого рехнуться можно.

Comment: Ага, то, что с "ульк", меньше человека. Это как бы норма. Поэтому не звучит. Со вторым то же.

Comment: Ну довольно таки креативненько получилось)

Answer (score 1):

1. Почему эта задача показалась мне **интересной**? Решенных аналогов у этого примера не было, но сама задача была понятна. Это **повтор однокоренных слов** с разной исходной формой письма и разными семантическими оттенками [по толковому словарю.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)

***Быстро*** (нейтр.) – это происходящий с большой скоростью, а ***по-быстрому*** (разг. ) –  не мешкая, не теряя времени. Собирайся по-быстрому. Сворачивайте всё и по-быстрому.

2. Форма написания подобных сочетаний  обычно **дефисная** (ср. мало-помалу, точь-в-точь, тет-а-тет), но это слова с **нормированным** написанием, а эта тема контролируется **словарем**.  Поэтому первый вариант  «быстро-по-быстрому» будет однозначно **неправильным.**
3. Связь между словами-повторами является **сочинительной**. Это может быть однородное перечисление или дефисная запись, например: *Одна в глуши лесов сосновых **Давно, давно** ты ждешь меня* (П.). ***Давно-давно**, много-много лет назад, — сказал я, — землю нашу покрывали леса.*
4. Но формы с запятой  не было у автора, а дефисная форма не подошла. Тогда остается **подчинительная связь**. Грамматически это возможно (наречие, отнесенное к другому наречию), а семантику можно рассматривать как неоднородную в соответствии со словарем.
5. Уже было предложено два варианта оформления (1) ***быстро, по-быстрому***; (2) ***по-быстрому быстро***. Всё разобрали!))

Но текст автора  менять нежелательно, как и выбирать другую форму письма…
Тогда, может, **присмотреться к тире?**  Этот знак отвергли все и сразу.

Итак, ***туда-сюда быстро – по-быстрому...***?  Не так уж он и плох... А если переставить запятую?

6. Мой вариант:

*Тысчонки гирлянд, в пустынчонке, лунным таки песком засыпанной, висящие туда-сюда, **быстро** – **по-быстрому были-таки дотла сожжены**.*

Здесь второе наречие уточняет первое и обособлено тире. Значение: сожжены ***быстро-поспешно***.

Comment: Лучше написать "без исправлений в авторском тексте". Раньше вы говорили, что сначала обязательно надо отредактировать (чтобы всё было корректно). А сейчас что? Даунгрейт? Тем же словом не уточняют, из-за того что то же слово не может дать больше самого себя. В словарях у "по-быстрому" значение "быстро", а вы это скрыли. Быстро — это тоже не мешкая, не теряя времени (*Собирайся быстро. Сворачивайте всё, и быстро*).

Comment: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=быстрый

Comment: Посмотрите другие словари. *Поэтому первый вариант «быстро-по-быстрому» будет однозначно неправильным* — псевдологический вывод, одно из другого не следует. Нам нельзя образовывать слова, нельзя соединять слова? Можно только составителям словарей?

Comment: Словари словарями, а художественный текст текстом. Слово с двумя дефисами не пройдет контроль.  Составленное вами – сленг!  (И соблюдайте правила честной игры... Это без подробностей. ) Собирайся быстро и собирайся по-быстрому –  есть разница? Это и без словарей должно быть видно.

Comment: Надо было так и написать. Ну тогда чего вы его выбрали в конце? И в чём разница? Разве что в ракурсе. В "по-быстрому" больше образа действия. "Собирайся быстро" можно произнести с такой интонацией, что смысл будет таким же. Что именно сленг?

Comment: Сленг - все слова, придуманные кем-то. Или авторские неологизмы. Но не нормированная речь, что плохо в данном случае. Норму не надо нарушать, а подходящий синтаксис можно выбрать.

Comment: Я еще думаю о последней запятой. Может, ее убрать из авторского текста, тогда смысл будет "сожжены по-быстрому". Логика есть. Как считаете? Мне он теперь больше нравится, а всё остальное выглядит притянутым за уши.

Comment: Это "быстро, то есть по-быстрому". Из разряда "Капитан Очевидность". *Сленг - все слова, придуманные кем-то* — это неверно, учите матчать. Но это задумку меняет, смысл редакторам нельзя менять.

Comment: Специально для вас: Сленг (англ. slang) — набор слов или новых значений существующих слов, **употребляемых в различных группах**.

Comment: Я знаю, что такое сленг.  Ладно, спасибо, пока!